# Difference between "testified" and "stated" in a legal context

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, legalese

If you're working in a law firm, do the words "testified" and "stated" have two different meanings?

For example,

> The witness testified that...
>   The witness stated that...

And is it acceptable to use the two as synonyms?

Answer (score 2):

[Black's Law Dictionary online](http://thelawdictionary.org/state-v/) states:

> **What is STATE, v? To express the particulars of a thing in writing or in words; to set down or set forth in detail. To set down in gross; to mention in general terms, or by way of reference; to refer. Utica v. Richardson, 6 Hill (N. Y.) 300. Read more: What is STATE, v? definition of STATE, v (Black's Law Dictionary)**

[It also](http://thelawdictionary.org/testify/) states:

> **What is TESTIFY? To bear witness; to give evidence as a witness; to make a solemn declaration, under oath or affirmation, in a judicial inquiry, for the purpose of establishing or proving some fact. See State v. Robertson, 26 S. C. 117, 1 S. E. 443; Gannon v. Stevens, 13 Kan. 459; Nash v. Hoxie, 59 Wis. 384, 18 N. W. 408; O’Brien v. State, 125 Ind. 38, 25 N. E 137, 9 L. R. A. 323; Mudge v. Gilbert 43 How. Prac. (N. Y.) 221. Testimonia ponderanda sunt, non numeranda. Evidence is to be weighed, not enumerated. Read more: What is TESTIFY? definition of TESTIFY (Black's Law Dictionary)**

There are lots of specialized dictionaries on the Net. It's a good idea to do research before asking a question that you can answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You testify under oath. Part of the testimony is what you state. You can also state things outside of the legal proceedings.

Comment: You put to words what I already know/knew instinctively. Thank you. I think it's a matter of my confidence in myself.